# How to show that quantum theory conforms to laboratory behavior of pendulums

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, harmonic-oscillator

In the last assignment given to me by my professor, there is a question which asks:

> In classical theory, it says that in presence of air friction, a pendulum continuously loses energy with time and its amplitude also decreases with time. However according to quantum theory, the pendulum loses energy only in discrete packets or quanta. This would lead to a decrease in the pendulum's energy in a step-wise manner. How can you show that there is no contradiction between quantum theory and the observed behavior of laboratory pendulums and springs?

---

What I want to know now is:  
*What exactly do I have to show mathematically to prove this result? I mean what kind of an equation will I have to derive or prove in order to answer this question? What will be the final equation after writing which I can say that "So this concludes that there is no contradiction."* I am completely clueless about what to do, right now. I don't want the complete answer or proof however.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a homework question; we would really prefer you discuss the things you have already thought about. The key question you need to consider is what the experimental effect of losing a single quantum of energy from a pendulum or spring would be. Imagine a quantum pendulum big enough that you could see it; what would happen if you could see its state change?

Comment: @zeldredge As part of another question. for a different pendulum, I actually calculated that losing one quantum of energy for a "big enough" quantum pendulum changes the amplitude of motion by almost one part in $10^{12}$ or even more. That is, the amplitude does not change considerably enough for us to visibly notice it.

Comment: In that case, I would guess that your professor just wants a qualitative answer that ties your previous calculations together...

Comment: @lemon I understand your statement, however, in that above mentioned problem, I used numerical values given in the question for the amplitude of motion, mass of bob, angular frequency, etc. What should I show for a general case?

Comment: If you've shown that the spacing of the energy levels of your pendulum are an undetectably small energy that seems sufficient to me.

Comment: @JohnRennie What about the equation of motion of the bob of the pendulum? Do I have to show some quantum version of this equation?

Comment: You'd have to show that the decoherence time of the pendulum is short, which would be a calculation far beyond undergraduate level. Since the question only asks about changes in the energy I suggest you restrict yourself to considering only the energy changes.

Comment: What exactly is "one quantum of energy" in relation to a pendulum? Whatever it is, you could compare the loss of "one quantum of energy" with the energy lost during a collision with an air molecule (air friction). But the question doesn't make much sense to me.